# Parallelise same function call | Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

Note: attempted solution at bottom is 1 sec *slower*.

Currently, I invoke `val_list = query(invoc, entries)` in a for loop. `val_list` is a list object that holds 4 return `strings`. There are 3 `val_list`s, as that is the `len(invoc_list)`.

Passing the no. `entries` was a way to speed up this script; as now there is only one invocation per input string.

How might I run `query()` processes in `parallel`?

Notebook:

```
import time
# GPT-2
from transformers import pipeline, set_seed
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
set_seed(42)

def query(payload, entries):
    list_dict = generator(payload, min_length=25, max_length=50, num_return_sequences=entries)
    output = [d['generated_text'].split(payload)[1].strip() for d in list_dict]
    return output

invoc_list = ['his her criminal charges include but are not limited to:', 'the defendant was sentenced to:', 'his her education history:']
entries = 4

%%time
for invoc in invoc_list:
    val_list = query(invoc, entries)
    print(val_list)
```

Example of 1 iteration's output:

```
>>> ['She attended the University of California at Los Angeles at an average of five years of her life.\n\nHer first impression of her "long-dead mentor" was an impression of a "dead body."', 'in 1948 he founded the Institute for Social Research (ISR).\n\nOn May 16 he was promoted to professor of applied economics at Cornell University. For the first time in his life he came out his own. He had', '"It was during these days that I started studying law in the United States and my own life began. With the help of my English teacher, I discovered that I could learn a new way to think."', '"He wrote a study on her character and his role as Queen, which I thought was amazing. And she loved reading stories, and I thought it was fascinating at the same time, that when you have people who read and']
Wall time: 32.6 s
```

```
%%time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

Q = Queue()

def runInParallel(func):
    proc = []
    for invoc in invoc_list:
        p = Process(target=func(invoc, entries))
        p.start()
        proc.append(p)

    Q.get()
    
    for p in proc:
        p.join()

runInParallel(query)
```

```
>>> Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:50256 for open-end generation.
```

Comment: change line to: `p = Process(target=func, args=(invoc, entries))`. or else you call the function in main process, and pass `None` to `target`

Comment: Running just your Process line update, on Jupyter Notebooks and Google Colab, has it run indefinitely, oddly. Note: I believe your alteration to be the standard way.

Comment: if it runs indefinitely, you have another problem.. if you call the function in the `Process` constructor, it's getting called in the main process, and not in the child process which defeats the point of multiprocessing.

Comment: you may need to `get` all the results from the queue before `join`ing the child processes. iirc that can cause deadlock

Comment: @Aaron I'll try this an update the above code as confirmation. One moment